# Что означает оператор *= или -=

Tags: c#, операторы

В качестве примера в учебнике есть вот такой код:

```
milesTraveled = endingMileage -= startingMileage;
amountOwed = milesTraveled *= reimburseRate;
```

Почему вместо обычных операторов умножения и вычитания использованы `*=` и `-=`. Они чем-то отличаются?

Comment: `milesTraveled = endingMileage -= startingMileage; ` преобразуется в `milesTraveled = (endingMileage = endingMileage -  startingMileage);` и раскроем скобки `endingMileage = endingMileage -  startingMileage; milesTraveled = endingMileage;`  и всё.

Comment: Выкиньте этот учебник в мусорку, такие примеры это тихий ужас.

Comment: @ixSci взял эту книгу из этого вопроса как рекомендуемую... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c

Comment: А что это за книга, как называется?

Comment: @ixSci Изучаем C#, Д. Грин, Э. Стиллмен

Comment: Лучше Троелсена читайте, а Head First это плохая серия, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо. Почитал бы, но в электронной версии нет, а цена на бумажную версию слегка кусается:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему вместо обычных операторов умножения и вычитания использованы
>   `*=` и `-=`.

Можете читать их буквально "умножить и провести присвоение" и "вычесть и провести присвоение".
Т.е. после проведения указанных операций не только изменится значения переменных `milesTraveled` и `amountOwed`, но и переменной `endingMileage`.

Пример с указанными операциями:

```js
let startingMileage;
let endingMileage;
let milesTraveled;
let amountOwed;
let reimburseRate;

startingMileage = 1;
endingMileage = 3;
reimburseRate = 10;

milesTraveled = endingMileage -= startingMileage;
console.log("milesTraveled:" + milesTraveled );
amountOwed = milesTraveled *= reimburseRate;

console.log("startingMileage:" + startingMileage + 
  ", endingMileage:" + endingMileage +
  ", milesTraveled:" + milesTraveled +
  ", amountOwed:" + amountOwed);
```

Comment: Но смысл такого действия от меня ускользает. Зачем нужно менять `endingMileage`?

Comment: то есть, если `endingMileage`=4 и `startingMileage`=1, то после этой операции `milesTraveled`=3 и `endingMileage`=3?

Comment: @AlexeyTen на вопрос "почему?" ответом, скорее всего, будет "это опечатка"

Comment: В общем надо смотреть в учебник. Может у этого есть глубокий смысл, хотя я тоже склоняюсь к опечатке.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis да, будет 3 и 3. В этом, кстати, можно убедиться, запустив этот код самостоятельно

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Добавил в ответ пример, обратите внимание на разные значения переменной с после первой операции и второй.

Comment: @Anamnian спасибо!

Comment: @Anamnian зачем вы разбили объявление и инициализацию переменных (аж 5 штук) на две строки? Код увеличился на 6 строк на ровном месте.

Comment: Вы не показали раскрытие скобок и операторов. А это главная "тонкость", которая непонятна в вашем ответе.

Comment: @Regent Люблю код читать сверху-вниз, а не сверху-вниз и слева-направо.

Comment: @nick_n_a По-моему мнению я словами достаточно объяснил как раскрываются данные операторы.

Comment: @Anamnian что вы подразумеваете под "слева-направо"? То есть `startingMileage = 1;` - это не "слева-направо", а `let startingMileage = 1;` - "слева-направо"?

Comment: @Regent на ваш второй вопрос ответ да, так как в первом случае выполняется 1 операция, во втором 2.

Answer (score 2):

Составные операторы "раскрываются" следующим образом:

```
milesTraveled = endingMileage -= startingMileage;
```

преобразуется в

```
milesTraveled = (endingMileage = endingMileage - startingMileage);
```

и раскроем скобки

```
endingMileage = endingMileage - startingMileage; 
milesTraveled = endingMileage;
milesTraveled = milesTraveled * reimburseRate;
amountOwed = milesTraveled;
```

Cмысл - более краткая запись.